# How to use RGB to set color of text in c#

Tags: c#, colors

I want to set the textcolor based on RGB values and I can not find any way of doing it.

Alternatively I am looking for something else to "target" with my rgb values, but I am super new to c# so it can not be too complicated or introduce too many things.

objects must have rgb values and seperate cordinates. When objects "touch" each other they will spawn a third object with a color that combines the rgb values of the previous two "collided" objects. This is all I want to do.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Color.FromArgb Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=net-6.0)

Comment: What ui-framework are you using? This seems a pretty common question, there is most certainly an answer on SO.